# gulp watch not minify

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

i new with gulp and i have a problem that i can't know why.

I want to minify my js and css, with the code below, works, but only works if i call minify-js and minify-css into default.

Gulp watch not work and i don't know why.

If a delete the .min with watch running, he creates the .min file, but came empty. All problems i have found came with solutions that my code already have.

```
        var css = [
            './css/estilo.css'
        ];

        var js  = [
            './js/app.js'       
        ];

        var gulp = require('gulp');
        var jsmin = require('gulp-jsmin');
        var rename = require('gulp-rename');
        var uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
        var concat = require("gulp-concat");
        var watch = require('gulp-watch');
        var cssmin = require("gulp-cssmin");
        var stripCssComments = require('gulp-strip-css-comments');

        gulp.task('minify-css', function(){
                 gulp.src(css)
                .pipe(stripCssComments({all: true}))
                .pipe(cssmin())
                .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/min/'));
        });

        gulp.task('minify-js', function () {
                 gulp.src(js)                        
                .pipe(jsmin())
                .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/min/'));        
        });

        gulp.task('default', function() {
            gulp.start('watch');

        });

        gulp.task('watch', function() {
            gulp.watch(js, ['minify-js']);
            gulp.watch(css, ['minify-css']);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    gulp.task('default', function() {
        gulp.start('watch');

    });
```

to:

```
    gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

This will set the default task's dependency as watch, running watch when default is called.

Also, instead of running `gulp`, you can run `gulp watch` to start watching your files. If you make a change to `./css/estilo.css` or `./js/app.js`, gulp will change it automatically.

Make sure safe write is turned off in your editor (if you use [JetBrains this guide should work](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/system-settings.html)), and the `/css` and `/min` directories have been created.

Comment: The trigger its working, he creates estilo.min.css but he cames empty, and answer the probable next question, yes he minify when its in default the functions, just watch not working.

Comment: He creates the file in right spot, just the file came empty when watch its running, and the trigger its activated

Comment: I recreated your setup and ran the gulp file and it works fine. So it sounds like you have an error in your CSS causing something to go wrong. To make sure, can you delete everything from `estilo.css` and replace it with something simple like `body {color: red}`. Start your gulp watch and change `red` to `blue`. Does that compile now as you expect?

Comment: Same problem, and i tried with different servers. The trigger its working, he reads the name of the file, creates the file, just the file cames empty when i save him with changes

Comment: @MadScone I agree. Sounds like it's a CSS issue

Comment: @MadScone i change the css, same problem, he cames empty with watch, just works with default. And it's not a problem from permission or something.